# Creating a new user after extending Django user model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Cant seem to find a response that clearly answers my question.

If you extend the Django user model with basic code like:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How does this affect creating a new user? Is `employee` class object automatically created when you create a new user? If the `department` field is required, how do you create a user object and employee object at the same time?

Comment: If you want Employee to extends the User class, Employee should extends "User" and not a models.Model. Thus Employe is a User with a departement field.

Comment: Is that true? I got that code directly from the Django documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Reading your question  (ie : create a user object and employee object at the same time), I thougth that you wanted Employee to extends User. It is is possible to create an Employee that is also a User because it inherit from it, you just instantiate an Employee. But, if the framework show you one way to do it, by all means follow the "django's way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `employee` object is not created automatically. To create a `user` object and an `employee` object at the same time, you can use the `user` instance as such

```
employee = Employee(user=user, depatment='xyz')
employee.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to create a employ instance at time or user creation you can use django signals which will create instance automatically when new user is created.

## models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import *
from __future__ import unicode_literals

class Employee(models.Model):

    userName = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __str__
        return unicode(self.userName)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
    Employee.objects.create(userName=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

This will automatically create a employee instance (blank instance data can be add after) when new user is created.

If you wish to extend user model and want to add further information while creating user you can use django-betterforms (http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html)

## models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import *
from __future__ import unicode_literals

class Employee(models.Model):

    userName = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __str__
        return unicode(self.userName)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import *

class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ('userName',)


class addEmployeeMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user':UserCreationForm,
        'profile':EmployeeForm,
    }
```

## views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

class addEmployee(CreateView):
    form_class = addEmployeeMultiForm
    template_name = "addEmployee.html"
    success_url = '/your url after user created'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form['user'].save()
        profile = form['profile'].save(commit=False)
        profile.userName = User.objects.get(username= user.username)
        profile.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

## urls.py

```
from .views import *

           urlpatterns = [
                 url(r'^addemp/$', addEmployee.as_view(), name='addemp'),
           ]
```

## addEmployee.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}     
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
     </body>
</html>
```